# Splitting X Y coordinates in list for MatPlotLib

Tags: python, numpy, hilbert-curve

I'm working on a program that involves the use of the Hilbert curve python module. The output of the Hilbert curve python module comes in the form of a list, or in the form of a single point set. I'm having trouble separating the list so that I can plot it using matplotlib.

Here's the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from hilbertcurve.hilbertcurve import HilbertCurve
import regex as re


p=int(input("order of curve: "))
n=2
hilbert_curve = HilbertCurve(p,n)

totalpoints = 2**(p*n)

distances = list(range(totalpoints))
#distances = list(range(int(input("list the number of points"))))

points = hilbert_curve.points_from_distances(distances)


#This stuff below prints out all of the individual points
#for point, dist in zip(points, distances):
#    print (f'point(h={dist}) = {point}')

#this prints out the array of all points generated by the program. Useful for debug
#print(points)
```

The issue is, while using matplotlib it doesn't separate the individual points in 'points' resulting in multiple linear plots instead of a Hilbert curve.

I also need to be able to separate them so I can perform arithmetic on the individual points. This library infinitely expands the length of the curve rather than defining it within a single 1x1 square how the curve should be represented. This is something easily resolved by dividing the individual points.

The end result of the product is to be able to determine a starting point for the Hilbert curve instead of having it start at 0,0. The second implementation will be in a point finding script where the generated points of a Hilbert curve can be checked against specific points to see if the curve passes through it. So, for both implementations I need to be able to manipulate the individual points which I can't in the current list form.

I have attempted to use the np split() as well as the `str.split()` methods. the str methods fails due to this being a list, not a string. np isn't working for an unknown reason.

Comment: are you perhaps looking for `x, y = point`? if you want to create a list of xs and ys you can do a for loop over points and add x to xs and y to ys. Regarding your second question: it's called normalization. You should find absolute max values for x and y, then divide by them to normalize to a range between -1 and 1 (or if you want the bounding box to have a size of 1x1, divide by 2*max(abs(xs or ys))

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about how to do the loop for the x and y point but because points range from a single digit up to about 6 digits I couldn't figure out how to separate them in the for loop. I was thinking regex might work but I really don't understand regex expressions. As far as the normalization, that's thankfully something that I managed to figure out. Since the total length of a curve is just 2^n where n is the order of the curve we can calculate the max x fairly easily.

Comment: You could use NumPy. E.g `points_array = np.array(points); plt.plot(points_array[:, 0], points_array[:, 1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do what you want but is very inefficient if you have millions of points (6 digits):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = [[i,i**2] for i in range(10)]
xs=[]
ys=[]
for x,y in points:
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(y)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.show()
```

in this case, I suspect many of your points will be closer than 1px to each other, so instead you can add your points to a kd-tree (if your points are in 2 dimensions, which they seem to be, K will be 2) and query the points that are in your view port (assuming you have zoomed in to see the actual curve, instead of just a solid block of points, since that's what the Hilbert curve is doing(it is a space-filling curve)).

Imagine the same scenario for a fractal pattern (which a Hilbert curve is really) that has infinitely many points due to its recursive nature. You won't be drawing points that are nanometers apart when the pixels on your display are in the order of micrometers since they won't be visiblle.

Comment: I think that'll work perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: do you mind accepting the answer if this does what you want?

Comment: Just accepted it and implemented it today. It works perfectly, thank you so, so much!